# Extension of Erdős-Gallai (s,t)-path theorem to directed graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs, hamiltonian-paths, erdos

The following is a result of Erdős-Gallai from 1959 (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02024498):

*Given a 2-connected undirected unweighted graph with minimum degree at least $d$, for every pair of vertices $s$, $t$, there is an $(s,t)$-path of length at least $d$.*

Is there a known extension of this theorem to directed graphs? In particular, is the answer to the following question known?

*Given a 2-strongly-connected directed unweighted graph with minimum in- and out-degree at least $d$, is it the case that for every pair of vertices $s$, $t$, there is an $(s,t)$-path of length at least $d$?*